# Is there any sqlite API (C API) alternative to BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT

Tags: c++, sql, c, database, sqlite

In sqlite we can do BEGIN TRANSACTION and then COMMIT after any update or insert operation to ensure atomic feature of databases. Can I achieve same using sqlite C APIs ?

Eg :

```
*BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE accounts
   SET balance = balance - 1000
 WHERE account_no = 100;

UPDATE accounts
   SET balance = balance + 1000
 WHERE account_no = 200;

INSERT INTO account_changes(account_no,flag,amount,changed_at) 
VALUES(100,'-',1000,datetime('now'));

INSERT INTO account_changes(account_no,flag,amount,changed_at) 
VALUES(200,'+',1000,datetime('now'));

COMMIT;*
```

I want to do above in C/C++ program using C/C++ APIs of sqlite

Comment: You can't use a C++ API in a C program.

Comment: @ThomasSablik, I dont want to do it in C program specifically, I just want to know if there are any APIs in C or C++

Comment: Er. you just execute them the same way you'd execute any sql statement... `sqlite3_exec()` works well since they don't return anything and don't need any values bound to parameters.

Comment: _"I want to do above in __C program__ using C/C++ APIs of sqlite"_ Your question should contain all necessary information. Don't change your question in the comments. Edit your question.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I just want to know alternative C or C++ APIs  if there are any for BEGIN TRANSACTION & COMMIT, Im not bothered C or C++ program I will code it in.

Comment: @Shawn, Thanks for the reply, It solves my problem. Thanks for addressing right part of question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below `c` API to execute any properly formed `sql` statement.

```
int sqlite3_exec(
  sqlite3*,                                  /* An open database */
  const char *sql,                           /* SQL to be evaluated */
  int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),  /* Callback function */
  void *,                                    /* 1st argument to callback */
  char **errmsg                              /* Error msg written here */
);
```

For example, to begin the transaction

```
sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN TRANSACTION;", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

To commit the transaction

```
sqlite3_exec(db, "END TRANSACTION;", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Where `db` is your `sql` connection.

> Note:: `END TRANSACTION` is just an alias for `COMMIT`.